# Dynamic query executer

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports, sybase

I'm trying to write *JasperReports* report supporting multiple databases (Sybase/Oracle). In Sybase you can write simple sql while in Oracle most of the time you need plsql for example while using procedures or function. Because of that you need 2 or more query language. Is there any way to change query language by passing parameter to report or writing your own Query Executor Factory. Any help would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can pass SQL to report filling engine as a parameter, but you need to use special parameter syntax. So in the SQL statement put something like below.

```
$P!{my_query}
```

JasperReports will consider this parameter like a kind of place holder (note the special syntax $P!{}) which will be replaced with the text value of the parameter. You need to set default value for this parameter as ireport need to know fields available in result-set.

Pass the actual SQL at the runtime as parameter